Is "I pass the trimmer" correct?
When we use the mower, we say we mow the lawn.
When we use a trimmer, what is the phrase or expression we can use?
Is it something like in French as We pass the trimmer or other expression?
Thank you for your answer.

We trim the lawn edges?

As prosaic as 'I used the strimmer' or 'I trimmed the edges of the lawn with the strimmer'. 'Strimmer' is perhaps the more usual term in the UK.

Yup, we mow with a mower and trim with a trimmer. Nothing more needed.

No, "I pass the trimmer" is not idiomatic usage. With no other context, I would interpret it to mean you're passing the trimmer to someone else, not passing the trimmer over the lawn.
There's no particular verb I know of to describe the use of a string trimmer. The only specific options would be to use the noun as a verb, as in "I string-trimmed the lawn," or more colloquially, "I weed wacked the lawn".
You could also use less specific verbs like
"I used the string trimmer on the lawn" or "I did a pass with the weed wacker". You could also describe particular things you're doing with the tool, for example, using it to clean up the edges of a garden bed is referred to as "edging". That said, one can edge a lawn without using a string trimmer, or use a string trimmer for purposes other than edging.

Certainly barbers and whatnot pass the trimmer or pass the scissors over someone’s head/hair/beard. Works for "haircuts" for plants too, e.g.: “I passed the trimmer over the shrubs.”

@TinfoilHat Yes, you could pass the trimmer over something. But to simply "pass the trimmer" is probably to hand it to someone else.
